# Mysql parameterized Views

Tags: mysql, view, mariadb

I want to know how mysql views optimised for where clauses. I have created one mysql view.

```
CREATE VIEW `testView` AS
select ID from `table1`
union
select ID from `table2`
```

when I fire this query

```
select * from testView where some_col = 'some_val'
```

what will mysql do after firing this query.

Is mysql takes all the rows from table1 and table2 in memory and then fire where clause?

OR

Directly this query get fired internally?

```
select ID from `table1`  where some_col = 'some_val'
union
select ID from `table2`  where some_col = 'some_val'
```

Comment: *Is mysql takes all the rows from table1 and table2 in memory and then fire where clause?* Yes. Except the view data may be cached on disk (especially when it is too huge for to fit into available memory).

Answer (score 0):

First, a `VIEW` is syntactic sugar around a `SELECT`.  So, let me discuss the selects:

```
select ID from `table1`
union
select ID from `table2`
```

By default, that is `UNION DISTINCT`, so this is what happens:  (`UNION ALL` would be quite different)

1. Create a temp table with one column.
2. Read the ID column from table; copy all them as rows into the temp table
3. Ditto for table 2
4. Deduplicate that temp table
5. Deliver the rows.

For this:

```
select * from testView where some_col = 'some_val'
```

If there is no relevant index, it will read the entire table, checking each row for the `WHERE` clause.  As it runs, it delivers the rows (all columns) that are not filtered out.

If it has the optimal `INDEX(some_col)`, it may do as above, or it may do:

1. Reach into the index to find the first row matching that `WHERE` clause.
2. Scan forward in the B+Tree until the clause fails.
3. For each matching `some_col`, deliver the row.

For this:

```
select ID from `table1`  where some_col = 'some_val'
union
select ID from `table2`  where some_col = 'some_val'
```

It is like your first `UNION`, except that each of the tables may or may not have a useful index, hence will (or won't) be optimized based on your other "where" sample.  (At least 4 possible ways to evaluate.)

If your last thing is actually the body of a `VIEW`, there is the added complication of whether the Optimizer chooses to "materialize" the contents, then do the filtering, or "merge" the caller's stuff with the `VIEW`.  This gets even messier to explain and spell out.

Use `EXPLAIN ...` and/or `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON ...` to get more information.  (Come back if you want an explanation of the `EXPLAIN` output; it is usually somewhat cryptic.

Keep in mind that seemingly tiny changes can make a big difference in how the query is performed.